# Unable to install Sverchok on 2.80 - Could anyone help

Tags: add-on, installation, sverchok

I downloaded Sverchok from Github - but when I try to enable it I am getting the following error:

[image: Sverchok Installation Error]

I am using Blender 2.80 Portable on Win 10 64bit.
I have no problem installing any other add-ons or Installing the older version of Sverchok on Blender 2.79b Portable.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blender Python API has undergone changes in the 2.8 release. Sverchok hasn't been fully update for Blender 2.8 yet, however a pre-release version of the add-on is available. You can find the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/2326). The [milestones for porting the add-on to 2.8](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/milestone/3) can be viewed on GitHub as well.

Comment: Thank you. It worked - although it's not 2.80/scripts/addons_contrib as the instruction says. It should be just 2.80/scripts/addons_contrib

Comment: @saicode I have to admit I'm struggling to see the difference between `2.80/scripts/addons_contrib` and 
`2.80/scripts/addons_contrib`

Comment: my bad it should just be
2.80/scripts/addons

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide explicitly for installing Sverchok for 2.8 here:
https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/2326

:)

Comment: Thank you. It worked - although it's not 2.80/scripts/addons_contrib as the instruction says. It should be just 2.80/scripts/addons_contrib

How do you find the instructions? I wend up and down on the Sverchok page and couldn't find anything. I am still not used to how the Github pages work.

Answer (score 0):

As @rjg and @morph3us mentioned the installation instruction can be found here https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/2326

Although the instruction seems to be a bit old - and you should put the Sverchok folder in the 2.80/scripts/addons **not** the 2.80/scripts/addons_contrib as the instruction says.
(In case it helps anyone else)